# Where can I edit the mySIte personal information (add some new items)

Tags: user-profile, template

I want to customize the right top part (see pictue - red box) for all our MySite pages.
The violet lines in the screenshot would be additional informations like "email address", "location", "short name (Account Name)" etc.)
What I would need, is a step by step desctiption how to edit this part (top right) for all mySite pages.

In the old version (SP2013 I added for exemple location, Account name etc.

But it's been a looong time since I did this. I honestly have no clue where I did this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/configure-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2016-step-by-step.html

And: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-sharepoint-server-2016-and-2019-ba84c8a3-3ce2-4252-926e-c67654ceb4a3

They are both in English but you can find the equivalent in German online.